# How to auto scroll gridview rows in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net. Please answer my question.

My grid view rows must automatically scrolling as soon as the page is loaded in asp.net. How could i do this.

Comment: Gridview rows scrolling? Horizontal alignment can be set by specfying the width of the itemtemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Add div as shown below and in that div add your gridview

```
 <div  style="height:100px; width:450px; overflow:auto;">

   //add your gridview code here

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll Through the Page**

You could use JQuery to do the auto scrolling on your page as below:

on your .aspx page you will have something like this:

> ```
>  <script>
>       $(document).ready(function () {
>         var container = $('body'), scrollTo = $('#destination');
>         $('html, body').animate({
>             scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
>         }, 900);
>       });
> </script>
>
> <div id="destination"></div>
> ```

and you can either use the div tag to scroll to a certain position or you could just pick up an id from any elements in your gridview row.

**UPDATE, Scroll bar on grid view**
The code above only scroll through the page but to create the scroll bar out of your grid view you need to set your container overflow attribute to scroll like

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; overflow: scroll">your GridView</div>
```